# Migrating from http to https in drupal 7 does not get static files

Tags: https, drupal-7

Recently, I migrated my website from `http://www.minag.gob.cu` to `https://www.minag.gob.cu` you can visit to watch what´s the matter.

The trouble is that css and js files are not downloading cause browsers say those are not secure files.

**How can I change the path in Drupal 7, to get those files over https?**

---

This is what browsers can download.

```
@import url("http://www.minag.gob.cu/sites/all/modules/textsize/textsize.css?p8w3zq");
```

But I want

```
@import url("https://www.minag.gob.cu/sites/all/modules/textsize/textsize.css?p8w3zq");
```

Comment: I solved it! I activated: $base_url = 'http://www.minag.gob.cu';  in settings.php and it worded!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your domain name with https in base_url variable in settings.php

Example:
$base_url = 'https://your_web.com'; //do not put trailing slash